# Tcl/Tk: 'moveto' position is off?

Tags: canvas, position, tcl

This is with Tcl/Tk-8.6.12+dfsg-1 (as packaged in Debian/sid).

I'm trying to position some element on a Tcl/Tk canvas.

Traditionally, there was the `canvas move` command, which would move tagged items relative to their current position.
As of Tcl/Tk-8.6, there's also a `canvas moveto` command, which *should* move tagged items to an absolute position.

However, for whatever reasons the two do not behave the same.

Consider the following minimal script (where I've put the output of `puts` in comments):

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish
canvas .c -width 100 -height 100 -background white
pack .c

.c create line 0 0 0 0 -tags tag
puts [.c coord tag]
# 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

.c move tag 100 100
puts [.c coord tag]
# 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0

.c move tag -100 -100
puts [.c coord tag]
# 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

.c moveto tag 100 100
puts [.c coord tag]
# 102.0 102.0 102.0 102.0
```

As you can see, if I position an item at `+0+0`, its bounding box will be where i expect it.
If I then do a *relative* move to a new position, e.g. `+100+100`, the item is there as it should be.
I can also do a relative move back, and the item appears at the origin.

However, if I do an *absolute* move to the position `+100+100`, the item will really show up at `+102+102`.
For my use-case this offset by 2 pixels in each dimension is not tolerable (as items are going to be positioned pixel-accurately)

What's going on here?

What's the use-case of `moveto` if it doesn't actually move the item to the requested position?

(sidenote: what is the correct tag for `Tcl/Tk` questions? why is `tk` an alias for `tkinter`, and `tcltk` for questions about an R-module?)

**EDIT**: i only observe this behaviour with a `line` item. If i instead use `.c create rectangle 0 0 0 0 -tags tag` the corrdinates are correct...

Comment: I'm not entirly sure about this, but you may consider this. Tcl/Tk states on its own that it is +-1 pixel accurate. I believe this is due [dpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels#direct2d-and-dpi) scaling and results are threat as whole numbers while it actually is a float.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. The [Tcl Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.html#M17) states that:

> All coordinates related to canvases are stored as floating-point
> numbers. Coordinates and distances are specified in screen units,
> which are floating-point numbers optionally followed by one of several
> letters. If no letter is supplied then the distance is in pixels. If
> the letter is m then the distance is in millimeters on the screen; if
> it is c then the distance is in centimeters; i means inches, and p
> means printers points (1/72 inch). Larger y-coordinates refer to
> points lower on the screen; larger x-coordinates refer to points
> farther to the right. Coordinates can be specified either as an even
> number of parameters, or as a single list parameter containing an even
> number of x and y coordinate values.

I'm not entirly sure about this, but you may consider this. Tcl/Tk states on its own that it is +-1 pixel accurate. I believe this is due [dpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels#direct2d-and-dpi) scaling and results are threat as whole numbers while it actually is a float and it rounds up sometime.

Comment: so why would it work with lines using relative coordinates, and rectangles using absolute coordinates; but not lines using absolute coordinates?

Comment: @umläute besides some basic statements I don't know to read tcl. But I think you would find it in the source code on github, since it is a open source project. I didn't try to answer your question, I tried to help with a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: sure, and thanks for the effort. regardless, my comment was supposed to say why i don't think that is an answer to my question (and why i won't *accept* it unless convinced otherwise)

Comment: @umläute fair enough. I just had another idea. Set the highlightthickness and the borderwidth to 0 and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: The canvas rendering engine usually has to round to integers to show things (and probably just does it in a simple-minded way). The *logical* coordinates are all floating point numbers; those are what is used for things like overlap decisions.